# mapbBox rendering causes sometimes blank for few area in the map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Sometimes my map is rendering empty blank spaces in right corner of the map once on clicking the marker icon.

[image: map diaplay is sjown]

I m using leaflet.js and mapbox.js and this issue occurs only in few cases .

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed in latest version of mapbox(need to update leaftet). Please upgrade your mapbox.